# "Нипочему" — есть ли такое слово в современном русском языке?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, слитно-раздельно, ни

Мне встретилось **обсуждение этого вопроса** в Интернете [«Нипочему» — есть такое слово?](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4055005-nipochemu--est-takoe-slovo.html#reply3322348)

Действительно, орфографический редактор подчеркивает его, а в орфографическом словаре РАН указано: искомое слово **отсутствует**.

В то же время был принят ответ: "Разговорное, не сленг какой-то и не диалектное, а вполне нормальное слово. Пользуйтесь смело". Была дана ссылка **на словарь Ожегова**, но вот примеров из литературы не было.

**Так как же быть?** Пользоваться смело или все-таки не стоит рисковать? И существуют ли **примеры** из литературы со слитным написанием частицы НИ?

И еще интересно: почему слово **исключили** из современных словарей и можно ли писать НИ **раздельно**?

Comment: Существующее слово должно быть независимым. А это можно использовать только как ответ на "почему?". Поэтому и исключили.

Comment: oleedd, у вас логика инопланетная, откуда вы берете свои суждения?
А вот здесь нет вопроса: «Швейцар долго не хотел нас впускать, просто так, ни почему, и мы жалко и без обиды толклись у дверей… [Булат Окуджава. Искусство кройки и житья (1985)] Да и текст не новый –  значит, и тогда этим словом (нипочему) не пользовались и в словарь Ожегова не смотрели. Что скажете?  (И опять отвечаете в комментариях.)

Comment: Из космоса. Там существа гораздо умнее, чем вы. Ну ладно, кто его знал, что так кто-то может употребить. Но для полноценного слова нужно такое: *Он сделал это нипочему.* Ну всё равно употребление очень ограничено, такого не бывает с существующими словами, поэтому я против.

Comment: Мне показалось, что для ответа этого очень мало.

Comment: Другим так не кажется.  Или надо было распространить ответ, добавить что-нибудь философское.

Comment: А я не люблю философствовать и лить воду, как вы (иногда) :) У меня конкретика всегда (то есть чёткость и доступность), научный подход, а такой информации обычно мало.

Comment: Опять переходите на мою личность?  Кстати, в конкурсе будете участвовать? Там как раз ваша краткость  и доступность нужна. Ну и научный поход тоже не помешает.

Comment: А вы так часто сами делали. Получилось, как в отместку. Не, не сильно в теме, потом загляну в кое-какой словарь.

Comment: На вашу личность интересно переходить, вы нестандартно реагируете. Так будете участвовать? Какие словари!  Представьте наглядно три ситуации, когда можно использовать  вводное сочетание. И проявите свои космические способности.  О конце чего мы в каждом случае говорим? Хорошая подсказка!

Comment: Потому что устали уже это обсуждать?

Comment: А я устала слушать длинные  и бесконечные речи тех, кто обсуждает.  Вы заметили, что мой вопрос имеет и второе значение  – когда наступит конец этим дебатам?  Может, проблема того не стоит и имеет простейшее решение?

Comment: Не заметил) Это завуалировано. Думал, что то просто шутка. Оно похоже на "в любом случае".